# Ping ubuntu running inside VMPlayer

Tags: vmware-player

I have installed Ubuntu in Windows 8 using **VMwarePlayer**. I do not know how can I PING the Ubuntu OS from a different Machine .

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's important to know you can ping a device only if devices are on the same network.I have used vmware a long time before.
I don't exactly remember icon's name but there are icons in right side at bottom,one of them is to change your network mode,vmware doesn't uses bridge mode by default.
1) Change your mode to bridge mode,and then set your ip(IPV4) address to any private ip            (for eg. 10.1.1.1) address in ubuntu.
2) Then go to network and sharing setting in windows and change ip(IPV4) address of your vmware adapter to some other private ip address(for eg 10.1.1.2) which is on same network as ubntoo.
3) Now both machines are on same network and you can ping one from another.I HOPE THIS HELPS YOU.